# How to pass multiple parameters to stored procedure on .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I wrote a function years ago, and works perfectly until migrate to .NET Core 3.1. Now parameters has not pass to SQL Server. My function is:

```
public async Task<IList<string>> GetTree(GetPayload payload)
{
    var cx = this.uow.Repository<Organization>().Context;

    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Code) == false)
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", payload.Code));

    if (payload.ParentId.IsNullOrEmpty() == false)
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parentId", payload.ParentId));
    
    var orgRes = await cx.Organization.FromSqlRaw("SP_GetOrganization", parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
  
    return orgRes
}
```

When debug this code, parameters succesfully come to API. But when SQL call with 'FromSqlRaw', parameters as shown '0'. Why?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @code nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @parentId uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @perId uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @isDeleted bit

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[SP_GetOrgTree] 
   @code
  ,@parentId
  ,@perId
  ,@isDeleted
GO
```

In SQL, when edit code like this: procedure is run with no problem. How can I fix this in EF Core?

```
DECLARE @RC int
    DECLARE @code nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @parentId uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @perId uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @isDeleted bit
    
    SET @code = 'sample code'
    
    EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[SP_GetOrgTree] 
       @code
      ,@parentId
      ,@perId
      ,@isDeleted
    GO
```

Comment: The docs are pretty clear. There's no need to use `ToArray()` either, or even a list. The `parameters` parameter is a `params` array, which means you can pass any number of parameter values directly. Whatever the problem is has nothing to do with passing multiple parameters

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Code) == false) etc - is it okay with payload? BTW, you don't need to write "==false", just if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Code))

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? What does `parameters as shown '0'.` mean? Does the payload have any values to begin with? Perhaps the names don't match? What does the stored procedure look like, and why is a *variable* number of parameters passed to a *single* stored procedure? Stored procedures don't have variable parameter arrays.

Comment: I suspect the data access code is needlessly convoluted. For starters, there's no need for explicit units of work or repositories. A DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet *is* a repository. Trying to get back the context hidden inside the UoW means the code is already leaking. Why use that stored procedure anyway, and why variable parameters? Are you trying to use a catch-all query perhaps? You wouldn't need to do that at all if you just used LINQ with different `.Where()` clauses as needed. A catch-all query *harms* performance too, and LINQ is a way to avoid that

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , when I remove the .ToArray() this error occurred: 

No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'List<SqlParameter>'.

I'm talking about a procedure that can take nullable value. This process was running before. For example, a GUID value comes from the payload. Regardless of this value, it is transmitted as 0 to the database side.

Comment: @SeattlePigeon it's impossible to guess what's wrong, except to say the data access code looks ... troublesome. Post the stored procedure and check the actual contents. You're asking people to guess about invisible code. I suspect the real solution would be to just ditch the unneeded custom UoW and repositories, and use EF Core properly

Comment: @SeattlePigeon so the List is empty actually? Provide us with the payload.

Comment: @SeattlePigeon using UoW and "repositories" (actuall, data-access objects) on top of another already-provided UoW and repository is an ugly *anti*pattern identified as early as 2009 by the main ORM authors. [Repository is the new Antipattern](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). You don't need them with EF Core -[No need for repositories and Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: Payload is not null completely. Let's say one or two parameter has sended.

Comment: Really big thanks to you @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: If you use EF Core properly, all you'd have to do is write something like `if (payload.Id !=null){ query=query.Where(org=>org.Id==payload.Id);}`, assuming `Id` is nullable. You can append multiple `Where` clauses this way to effectively create a `WHERE condition1 AND condition2 ....`.

Comment: Your solution is pretty clear but this procedure is really big and big calculation in there. I post just little piece of code. :/

Comment: @SeattlePigeon I already showed how to remove *all* of the posted code and replace it with a single `if`. As for your question - without the *code*, especially the stored procedure, you're asking us to guess.

Comment: @SeattlePigeon in fact, I'd guess that your code is making a call with parameters named `@@code` etc, while the stored procedure expects `@code`. All sproc parameters have null defaults though, so no error is ever raised, even though *no* parameter was used. [The docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) that the prefix is added by EF itself. You'd have to use `code` instead of `@code` as the SqlParameter name. Use SQL Server Extended Events, Profiler, or EF Core's query logging to see what is actually sent to the server.

Comment: @SeattlePigeon does `SP_GetOrganization` try to perform a hierarchical query, perhaps with a CTE or `hierarhcyid` field? You can create a *function* or view instead of a stored procedure to perform the hierarchical query, use it with `FromSqlRaw` and apply LINQ operators on top of it. Check [Composing with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq)

Comment: @SeattlePigeon if you don't want to post the code, at least try using `code` instead of `@code` as the parameter name.

Comment: The last edit contains just a call to another stored procedure. This doesn't help at all. What is that stored procedure's code? Besides, have you tried using `code` instead of `@code` in C#, ie `new SqlParameter("code", payload.Code)` and `new SqlParameter("parentId", payload.ParentId)` ?

Comment: I tried your solution but again, no way.. This exception is different:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The parameterized query '(@code nvarchar(4000),@parentId uniqueidentifier,@perId nvarchar' expects the parameter '@code', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the below code the values for `@parentId`, `@perId`, `@isDeleted` will be passed as `NULL`. You have to do the same from the `c#` when you call the SPROC.

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @code nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @parentId uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @perId uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @isDeleted bit

SET @code = 'sample code'

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[SP_GetOrgTree] 
   @code
  ,@parentId
  ,@perId
  ,@isDeleted
GO
```

Please see the below code to pass the `NULL` values. I'm modifying the same code. Please do the same for the other two parameters.

```
public async Task<IList<string>> GetTree(GetPayload payload)
{
    var cx = this.uow.Repository<Organization>().Context;

    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Code) == false)
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", payload.Code));
    else
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", DBNull.Value)); // Modified the code here

    if (payload.ParentId.IsNullOrEmpty() == false)
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parentId", payload.ParentId));
    else
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parentId", DBNull.Value)); // Modified the code here

    // Do the same for @perId, @isDeleted parameters. 
    // If they don't exist in your payload, just pass them as NULL directly

    // parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@perId", DBNull.Value));
    // parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@isDeleted", DBNull.Value));

    var orgRes = await cx.Organization.FromSqlRaw("SP_GetOrganization", parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();

    return orgRes;
}
```

Comment: And I'm not sure if you are having some extra logic in the SPROC. if it is direct `Select` from `Organization` table I recommend using `LINQ`. Eg: `.Where(x => x.Code == payload.Code)`

Comment: Still same. Result is never change with filter. :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve my problem. Big thanks guys. Here is the answer:

If one parameters can be null, check like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload.Code) == false)
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", payload.Code));
else
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", DBNull.Value));
```

and call procedure like this:

```
var orgRes = await cx.PdOrganizationTreeQuery
                   .FromSqlRaw("SP_Organization @code,@parentId,@perId,@isDeleted", parameters: parameters.ToArray())
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Note: all parameters MUST write at FromSqlRaw(). Because SQL Server expect those parameters.

Thanks to Sowmyadhar Gourishetty and Panagiotis Kanavos